# jQuery effects in menu

Tags: jquery, menu, click, html-lists

I'm trying to do a menu, and when you click one of the tags, it does some effects and css changes, but then, when I click another one, the one I clicked does not goes back to the first state, so it keeps the changes.

Here is my menu:

```
<ul id="navbar" class="col-md-24">
  <li><a href="#" class="menu">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu">Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="menu">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here my jQuery:

```
$('.text').hover(function(){
  $(this).find('.text').slideUp();
});
$('.menu').click(function() {
  $('.menu').not(this).slideDown();
    $(this).animate({
      width: "300px",
      height: "100px",
      'line-height':'60px',
      fontSize: "2em" 
    }).css({
      'border':'none',
      'background':'#fff',
      'padding': '20px 20px',
      'color':'#1b1b1b',
      'border-radius': '5px',
      'text-decoration':'none',
      'overflow': 'hidden'
    });       
  });
```

So, how do I do that when I click another menu tag, the one that I clicked before goes back to the state before I click? Someone told me I should use "active" class for the one is clicked, but I don't know how to add it to make it work.

Thank you

Comment: can you pls put it in a jsfiddle? and instead of giving the css in jquery, give it a class that has all those css.

Comment: Yes, JSFiddle would make it easier to help... but  : the fact is that if you apply some css on CLICK, then you have to remove it from the previously clicked item when you click on another one... you should have a function like "add_clicked_css" and "remove_clicked_css" that is called on all items/clicked item...

Comment: ooH I've never used this JSFiddle before and now I've seen that.... it is pretty cool!!! Here is http://jsfiddle.net/pp2yy26e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not easy guessing what you where really looking for when seeing your fiddle, but I think it might be like this:

Your HTML stays as it was:

```
<ul id="navbar" class="col-md-24">
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I added the mysterious *active-class* to your CSS putting in all the values you want to animate and made some adjustments. See comments in the code:

```
body {
    background-color:#1b1b2b;
}
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:80px;
}
ul#navbar {
    width:100%;
    display: block;
}
#navbar li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    vertical-align: top; /* makes the .menus stay at the top */
}
.menu {
    display: inline-block; /* important to animate the width */
    color:white;
    width: 100px; /* put in values so we can animate them */
    background:black;
    padding:10px 20px;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height: 1em; /* put in values so we can animate them */
    height: 1em; /* put in values so we can animate them */
    text-decoration:none;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s; /* here is the magic: CSS will do the animation*/
    /* when class .active is applied or removed */ 
}
.menu:hover {
    border:none;
    background:#fff;
    padding:20px;
    color:#1b1b1b;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.active { /* the CSS when the .menu is clicked on */
    border: 0 none;
    background:#fff;
    color: #1b1b1b;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 80px;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius:15px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

Now the JavaScript can be a lot more simple:

```
 $('.menu').click(function () {
     if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).removeClass('active');
         return;
     } else {
         $('.menu').removeClass('active');
             $(this).addClass('active');
     }
 });
```

Now there is only the class .active applied to and removed from the .menu links. CSS will do the rest.

[See the FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pp2yy26e/46/).